# In Login screen of Windows7 appears USER and ask for password

Tags: windows-7, malware

Today, for a first time, in my Windows 7 login screen has appeared a user account named "USER" and is asking for password.

Never saw something similar. I think a malware or virus has infected my Windows.

Does anyone has seen some similar situation? What should I do to gain access to my files?

Comment: So you had an account without a password? Can you log into that old user account?

Comment: I never used an account and password to login to Windows7. It was a surprised to me to see a windows login screen with and account named USER and asking for a password.

Comment: Most likely this was since always your account that you used with auto-logon. For some reason the auto-logon no longer works.  See some pointers in the link.